# Calculate several number ranges from numbers in an array

Tags: php

I'd like to calculate specific number rangers with a few numbers in an array.

In my array I do have the following numbers:

```
array(3500,3600,3700,3800,5000,5100);
```

Now I need the number range and the output would be:

```
1: 3500-3800
2: 5000-5100
```

Anyone an idea what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: 1. Where does `3800` come from? 2. What is the condition for 2 numbers to match the same range?

Comment: Shoudn't it be  `3500-3700` ?

Comment: What's the logic here? How did *3800* ended in the output

Comment: What exactly do you mean by number range?

Comment: Are you trying to split your number 'ranges' up in groups depending on intervals higher than 1000?
What's the exact purpose of the code?

Comment: We don't get what you mean.Please more specific.

Comment: I have a bunch of numbers and would like to sort them into groups (rounded to 100). Sample numbers are: 5029
3660
5055
5054
5048
5010
5024
5051
5046
5057
5009
5047
5053
3614
5060
5005
3669
3788
3723
3521
3623

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran Yes sorry I typed 3700 twice, corrected it.

Comment: Check out array_walk(_recursive) and anonymous functions

Comment: -1: You have "forgotten" to define "best way" in your question. Also it's not clear what hinders you to do what you want to do. Normally this is done with programming but your question does not contain any (pseudo) code nor a description why you feel unable to achiever what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented just for fun, thought it might be done in some elegant way but couldn't think of something better than this: (which is ugly)

```
$data = array(3500,3600,3700,3800,5000,5100);
sort($data);

$threshold = 100;

$result = array_reduce($data, function($result, $current) use($threshold) {
    end($result);
    $key = key($result);

    if ($key === null) {
        $result[] = array($current, $current);
    } elseif (!isset($result[$key][1]) || $result[$key][1] + $threshold >= $current) {
        $result[$key][1] = $current;
    } else {
        $result[] = array($current, $current);
    }

    return $result;
}, array());

var_dump($result);
```

Second attempt:

```
$data = array(3500,3600,3700,3800,5000,5100);
sort($data);

$threshold = 100;

$result = array_chunk(
    array_reduce($data, function($result, $current) use($threshold) {
        $last = end($result);

        if ($last !== false && $last + $threshold >= $current) {
            $result[count($result) - 1] = $current;
        } else {
            $result[] = $current;
            $result[] = $current;
        }

        return $result;
    }, array()),
    2
);

var_dump($result);
```